# Posts being viewed

Tags: query-posts, get-posts, views

I am looking for a way to list posts being viewed but I can't find anything online.

Is it even possible? I've seen some websites that have these loops, "What other readers are currently reading".

I'm using the following loop to list random set of videos

```
<?php      
      if ( is_home() ){
      $cat = get_query_var( 'cat' );
      query_posts(array('orderby' => 'rand', 'showposts' => 10, 'cat'=>$cat));
      }
      while (have_posts()) : the_post();
  ?>
```

How can I show posts being viewed? anyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest a way to implement this to be in the post template have a call that updates post meta with the current timestamp.  Then you can show posts that have been viewed recently by querying meta data for all values within a certain time range ordered by that timestamp.

Comment: Is it possible to tell wordpress to update the timestamp value if a post has been accessed?

Comment: Yes, I would store that in post meta and, as the answer states, I would suggest using a post template to update that post meta.